# Filter things with changeable arguments

Tags: javascript, function, object, filter, arguments

```
let products = [
{
    "name": "Lenovo",
    "price": "18000",
    "model": "v580c"
},
{
    "name": "Apple",
    "price": "30000",
    "model": "Iphone 6"
},
{
    "name": "Nikon",
    "price": "25000",
    "model": "G290"
}]
```

I need to filter my `products` array with `getProduct` function, which accepts changeable list of arguments.
Argument can be either the name of the **product** and/or price within the **minPrice**, **maxPrice**, and/or **model**.

```
function getProduct(productName, minPrice, maxPrice, productModel) {

    return products.filter(product => {
        return product.price < maxPrice && product.price > minPrice && product.name == productName;
    });
}

console.log(getProduct("Apple", 3540, 3000000000));
console.log(getProduct("Lenovo", 3540, 3000000000, "v580c"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send an array of params as argument and write a logic to process them accordingly.

**Sample:**

```js
function getProduct(array, params){
  var list = array.filter(function(o){
    return params.every(function(kv){
      if(o.hasOwnProperty(kv.key)){
        var cur = o[kv.key];
        switch (kv.operation){
          case ">":     return cur > kv.value 
          case "<":     return cur < kv.value 
          case "in":    return cur.indexOf(kv.value) > -1
          case "regex": return kv.value.test(cur)
          default:      return cur === kv.value 
        }
      }
    })
  });
  
  console.log(list);
  return list;
}

var products=[{name:"Lenovo",price:"18000",model:"v580c"},{name:"Apple",price:"30000",model:"Iphone 6"},{name:"Nikon",price:"25000",model:"G290"}];

getProduct(products, [{key:"name", value: "Nikon"}])
getProduct(products, [
  {key:"price", value: 20000, operation: ">"},
  {key:"price", value: 40000, operation: "<"}
])

getProduct(products, [{key:"name", value: "e", operation: "in"}])
getProduct(products, [{key:"model", value: /\d{2,}/g, operation: "regex"}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object with special structure for searching, if you need t search for more than one item. This proposal uses an object, with this structure for filtering:

```
{ 
    name: 'Apple',
    price: {
        min: 3540,  // both or a single border is possible
        max: 60000
    },
    model: function (s) { return s.match(/s/); } // just search for a single letter
}
```

The algorithm looks for every property in `search` and if *all* comparisons are true, then the element is added to the result set.

```js
function filter(array, search) {
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(search).every(function (k) {
            return (
                a[k] === search[k] ||
                typeof search[k] === 'object' && (
                    ('min' in search[k]) && ('max' in search[k]) && search[k].min <= a[k] && a[k] <= search[k].max ||
                    ('min' in search[k]) !== ('max' in search[k]) && (search[k].min <= a[k] || a[k] <= search[k].max)
                ) ||
                typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
            );
        });
    });
}

var products = [{ name: "Lenovo", price: "18000", model: "v580c" }, { name: "Apple", price: "30000", model: "Iphone 6" }, { name: "Nikon", price: "25000", model: "G290" }, { name: "Foo", price: "10", model: "a1" }, { name: "Foo", price: "20", model: "a2" }, { name: "Foo", price: "30", model: "a3" }, { name: "Foo", price: "40", model: "a4" }, { name: "Foo", price: "50", model: "a5" }, { name: "Foo", price: "60", model: "a6" }, { name: "Foo", price: "70", model: "a7" }, { name: "Foo", price: "80", model: "a8" }, { name: "Foo", price: "90", model: "a9" }];

console.log(filter(products, { name: 'Foo', price: { min: 60 } }));
console.log(filter(products, { name: 'Foo', price: { max: 40 } }));
console.log(filter(products, { name: 'Foo', price: { min: 40, max: 60 } }));
console.log(filter(products, { name: 'Apple', price: { min: 3540, max: 60000 } }));
console.log(filter(products, { name: 'Lenovo', price: { min: 3540, max: 60000 }, model: 'v580c' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of `min` and `max`. +1

Comment: Just  a suggestion, since you have made a really generic code, checking `search[k] === 'object'` for min/max does not look right. You can check for key instead.

Comment: @Rajesh, it was just an idea for an open API. it depends on the use, which parameters are needed, this is a proposal and not a final product (as always :-) )

Comment: @Rajesh, `in` works only on objects. if no object, the you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for ... in ...`.

Comment: Sorry to say but for the first time I think, I'd go with my code. `min` and `max` has added lot of conditions. Adding separate objects for separate query condition will keep API simple and make query more configurable. But its just my POV. There might be things I might have missed and hence came to this conclusion, but I guess failures and mistakes helps us to learn. :-) Have a good weekend.