# How to filter an array on different conditions using ES2016?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

In the below snippet we need to filter an array on based different AND , OR condition. 
Conditions

1. It should filter if filter object have "isFiltered" true.
2. PatternGroupCode "OTHER" means it include all fabrics except those
   fabrics marked "isFiltered" false.
3. Same "OTHER" condition is applied for fabricColor.

I am able to filter using fabricColor id. but not able to do using patternGroupCode.

```js
// all products
let products = [
  { name: "A", fabricColorGroupCodes:["OTHER"], patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColorGroupCodes:["BLUE"], patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 60 },
  { name: "C", fabricColorGroupCodes:["OTHER", "BLUE"], patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "D", fabricColorGroupCodes:["OTHER", "BLACK"], patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColorGroupCodes:["BLACK"], patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
  { name: "F", fabricColorGroupCodes:["BLACK"], patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "G", fabricColorGroupCodes:["GREEN"], patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 90 },
  { name: "H", fabricColorGroupCodes:["GREEN"], patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "I", fabricColorGroupCodes:["GREEN"], patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
 { name: "J", fabricColorGroupCodes:["GREEN"], patternGroupCode: 'PAISLEY', size: 80 }
];

function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  return array.filter(d => ( 
    Object.entries(filters).every(([k ,v]) => (
      Object.values(v).map(m => m.id).includes(d[k].id) 
    )) 
  ));
}

// filter conditions
// here we choose OTHER so it will filter on color BLACK and GREEN and 
// omit the BLUE because isFilter tag is false, same for patternGroupCode.
// so here it filter on SOLID , PLAID and WINDOWPANE and will omit PAISLEY .
let filters = {
  fabricColor: [
    {"id": 'BLACK', "isFiltered": true}, 
    {"id": 'BLUE', "isFiltered": false},
    {"id": 'OTHER', "isFiltered": true}
  ], 
  patternGroupCode: [
    {"patternGroupCode": 'OTHER', "isFiltered": true}, 
    {"patternGroupCode": 'STRIPES', "isFiltered": false}, 
    {"patternGroupCode": 'PLAID', "isFiltered": true}, 
    {"patternGroupCode": 'PAISLEY', "isFiltered": false}, 
    {"patternGroupCode": 'SOLID', "isFiltered": true}
  ]
};

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: just a another question, could you change the data format to a more filter friendly way, that you use a couple of key/value pairs instead of highly special names or nested object structures?

Comment: btw, is the second, third, ... filter an AND or an OR condition?

Comment: fabric color and patternGroupCode have AND condition

Comment: can you suggest data format for filter friendly so i will update accordingly

Comment: To understand, your current filter in the code means _color is not BLUE AND pattern is not (STRIPES or PAISLEY)_? Also, is it possible to not have `OTHER` in the filter and if yes, what's the expected output?

Comment: Yes we have OTHER in filter . So your expected result should be all patterns except PAISLEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the products in iterations for each filter with `reduce` (starting with the entire products array as the initial accumulator and returning a filtered version after applying each filter).

Also, since you were open to modifying the structure of your objects, I went ahead and made some small changes (removing the `id` from the `fabricColor` key in products and adding it to the `patternGroupCode` filter object) just to be consistent.

```js
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  return Object.entries(filters).reduce((acc, [k, kFilters]) => {
    let isFiltered = new Set(kFilters.filter(f => f.isFiltered).map(f => f.id)),
      other = kFilters.some(f => f.id === 'OTHER' && f.isFiltered),
      notFiltered = new Set(kFilters.filter(f => !f.isFiltered).map(f => f.id));
    return acc.filter(p => other ? !notFiltered.has(p[k]) : isFiltered.has(p[k]));
  }, array);
}


let products = [{
    name: "A",
    fabricColor: 'BLUE',
    patternGroupCode: 'PLAID',
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    fabricColor: 'BLUE',
    patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE',
    size: 60
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    fabricColor: 'BLUE',
    patternGroupCode: 'SOLID',
    size: 100
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    fabricColor: 'BLACK',
    patternGroupCode: 'PLAID',
    size: 70
  },
  {
    name: "E",
    fabricColor: 'BLACK',
    patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE',
    size: 80
  },
  {
    name: "F",
    fabricColor: 'BLACK',
    patternGroupCode: 'SOLID',
    size: 100
  },
  {
    name: "G",
    fabricColor: 'GREEN',
    patternGroupCode: 'PLAID',
    size: 90
  },
  {
    name: "H",
    fabricColor: 'GREEN',
    patternGroupCode: 'SOLID',
    size: 100
  },
  {
    name: "I",
    fabricColor: 'GREEN',
    patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE',
    size: 80
  },
  {
    name: "I",
    fabricColor: 'GREEN',
    patternGroupCode: 'PAISLEY',
    size: 80
  }
];

let filters = {
  fabricColor: [{
    "id": 'BLACK',
    "isFiltered": true
  }, {
    "id": 'BLUE',
    "isFiltered": false
  }, {
    "id": 'OTHER',
    "isFiltered": true
  }],
  patternGroupCode: [{
      "id": 'OTHER',
      "isFiltered": true
    },
    {
      "id": 'STRIPES',
      "isFiltered": false
    },
    {
      "id": 'PLAID',
      "isFiltered": true
    },
    {
      "id": 'PAISLEY',
      "isFiltered": false
    },
    {
      "id": 'SOLID',
      "isFiltered": true
    }
  ]
};

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: In my scenario patternGroupCode, fabricColor dont have same key for filter like ID.   So i cant modify patternGroupCode to ID.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to simplify the data structure to use a more simplified filter and a simplified filters object.

```js
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
    return array.filter(o =>
        Object
            .entries(filters)
            .every(([k, v]) => o[k] in v ? v[o[k]] : v.OTHER)
    );
}

var products = [
        { name: "A", fabricColor: 'BLUE', patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 50 },
        { name: "B", fabricColor: 'BLUE', patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 60 },
        { name: "C", fabricColor: 'BLUE', patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
        { name: "D", fabricColor: 'BLACK', patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 70 },
        { name: "E", fabricColor: 'BLACK', patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
        { name: "F", fabricColor: 'BLACK', patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
        { name: "G", fabricColor: 'GREEN', patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 90 },
        { name: "H", fabricColor: 'GREEN', patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
        { name: "I", fabricColor: 'GREEN', patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
        { name: "I", fabricColor: 'GREEN', patternGroupCode: 'PAISLEY', size: 80 }
    ],
    filters = {
        fabricColor: { BLACK: true, BLUE: false, OTHER: true },
        patternGroupCode: { PLAID: true, SOLID: true, STRIPES: false, PAISLEY: false, OTHER: true }
    },
    filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I agreed with simplyfying data structure . But what if we have complex data and filters ?

Comment: for a more complex filtering, you could have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273563/1447675), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume that we will be filtering products e.g. by **size**.

---

**Structure**

```
let products = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 60 },
  { name: "C", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
  { name: "F", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "G", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, patternGroupCode: 'PLAID', size: 90 },
  { name: "H", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, patternGroupCode: 'SOLID', size: 100 },
  { name: "I", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, patternGroupCode: 'WINDOWPANE', size: 80 },
 { name: "J", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, patternGroupCode: 'PAISLEY', size: 80 }
];
```

**Functionality**

```
const sizeAbove = value => o => o.size > value
const sizeBelow = value => o => o.size < value

products.filter(sizeAbove(90))
products.filter(sizeBelow(60))
```